# Inverting symbols in python 3.x

Tags: string, python-3.x, str-replace

I have a string:

```
a = '3+7-9'
```

I need to invert `'+'` into `'-'` and `'-'` into `'+'` in order to get

```
a = '3-7+9'
```

What is the proper way to do it using [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) without multiplying `* -1`?

Comment: multiplying with `*-1` will **not work**. This is a string. You cannot multiply a string with a negative number (well it will generate the empty string).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`str.translate(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and construct the map with [`str.maketrans(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
a = a.translate(str.maketrans("+-","-+"))
```

`str.maketrans("+-","-+")` will construct a dictionary:

```
>>> str.maketrans("+-","-+")
{43: 45, 45: 43}
```

so it maps the character with code `43` (which is `'+'`) on character `45` (which is `'-'`) and vice versa.

You can thus boost performance a bit by omitting the `str.maketrans(..)` part and write:

```
a = a.translate({43: 45, 45: 43})
```

This generates:

```
>>> a = '3+7-9'
>>> a.translate({43: 45, 45: 43})
'3-7+9'
```

If you know Linux's `tr` command you will notice that:

```
a.translate(str.maketrans("x","y"))
```

is equivalent to:

```
tr x y
```

(in the Linux shell)